# models.BooleanField interpret as integer

Tags: django

How can I interpret booleans (or '') as integers 0 or 1? so totals could be 0, 1 or 2, depending on the values of uno and dos.

```
class foo(models.Model)
    uno  = models.BooleanField()
    dos  = models.BooleanField()
    total = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default=int(0))
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # HUMDINGER....
        self.total = int(self.uno) + int(self.dos)
        super(Survey, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # Call the "real" save() method.
```

This is the error it is throwing for that line...

`invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm surprised that your `BooleanFields` have the empty string as their value. Regardless, since booleans evaluate to `0` and `1` in a numeric context, you can just do:

```
self.total = bool(self.uno) + bool(self.dos)
```

Comment: Maybe it's because I am using ModelForms?

Comment: @broinjc: That makes sense. `BooleanField` seems to interpret `''` as `False`, so everything looks fine to me...

Comment: yes. I ended up making a temporary list of my boolfields to iterate over and total `if listItem != ''`